# Grouped bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hello guys I am trying to draw a grouped bar  chart with d3js 
I want through several tutorials and finally tried with this code:

```
<script>
var data = [[10,20,30,40,50],[20,20,40,50,60]];
var canvas = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width",500)
    .attr("height",500);
    canvas.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("height",function(d){return d*10;})
        .attr("width",50)
        .attr("x",function(d,i){return i*60})
        .attr("y",function(d,i){return 500-(d*10);})
        .attr("fill","red");
</script>
```

There is some error. How to set data for grouped chart..

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051)?

Comment: Define "some error", we can't really help you much without know what the problem is. Also if you could reproduce it in jsfiddle or similar service it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, the error you're using is coming from the data structure that you've chosen.  The error is happening due to the way that the `.data(data).enter()` clause works.

The whole clause will implicitly iterate over the elements of the first level in your outter array.  That is each element `d` that is passed to

`.attr("height",function(d){...) .attr("x",function(d)...) and .attr("y",function(d)...)` is an array.  So, the internals of each function are operating with constants on the array, which makes no sense.  To clarify in javascript what does `d * [1,2,3,4]` mean?

To answer your second question. If you want to create a grouped bar chart check out this link: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051.